# Unicode в Python 3. Ошибка: NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Tags: python, excel, csv, xls, xlsx

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xlrd
import csv
from os import sys

def csv_from_excel(excel_file):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)
    all_worksheets = workbook.sheet_names()
    for worksheet_name in all_worksheets:
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
        with open('{}.csv'.format(worksheet_name), 'wb') as your_csv_file:
            wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            for rownum in range(worksheet.nrows):
                wr.writerow([unicode(entry).encode("utf-8") for entry in worksheet.row_values(rownum)])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_from_excel(sys.argv[1])
```

Это готовый модуль, но судя по всему для Python 2 а в третьем выскакивает ошибка **NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined**

```
        wr.writerow([unicode(entry).encode("utf-8") for entry in worksheet.row_values(rownum)])
```

Что поменять в этой строчке чтобы работало в Python 3

Comment: В третьем питоне `unicode` переименован в `str`

Comment: Если поставить `str` вместо `unicode` то вылезает другая ошибка **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

Comment: Измените параметры создания csv файла на `open('{}.csv'.format(worksheet_name), 'w', encoding='utf-8')`, затем измените запись в csv на `wr.writerow(worksheet.row_values(rownum))`.

Comment: @godva то что нужно, это решение моей проблемы

Answer (score 1):

Можно несколько упростить решение, воспользовавшись [модулем Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import sys
import csv
import pandas as pd

def excel_to_csv(excel_file, **kwargs):
    for sheet, df in pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=None).items():
        df.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(sheet), **kwargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    excel_to_csv(sys.argv[1], index=False,
                 encoding='utf-8', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```